# UIView + Swipe Gestures info

Tags: objective-c, multi-touch, swipe

i've just implemented a swipe gesture in my UIView, and I want it to 'move' according to the gesture.
Long story short, I need to get the current "X and Y" coordinates during the swipe, to move the UIView.

Currently I have a "Swipe Gesture" linked to my UIView, an IBAction linked to the Swipe and the working following code:

```
- (IBAction)mostrar_contas:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
     campo.text=@"OK";
}
```

BTW: the 'campo' thing is a test UITextField.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out UIPanGestureRecognizer - it gives you continuous feedback for current translation and velocity.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:myView];
```

EDIT: I'm not entirely sure if this works with a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. A `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, as suggested by [seejaneworkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627389/uiview-swipe-gestures-info/7627432#7627432) might be the better choice in this case.

Comment: Not quite sure how to use the 'UIPanGestureRecognizer', could you give me an example or a hint?

Comment: [Event Handling Guide for iOS: Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html)